# add qml item to Qt3DQuickWindow

Tags: qt, 3d, qml, qt3d

as you know Qt3DQuickWindow is a customized window that generated to show 3d entity on 3d scene and is a best alternative for 3dScene that can load all material independent to his implantation. (ability that 3dscene can not do in related to alpha and many other  customize material)

at this time i want show a 3d scene on Qt3DQuickWindow and show my qml item on top of 3d scene and 3d environment but there is no QQmlEngine in Qt3DQuickWindow for add my qml item to them .

is there any way can i overlay on top on qml 3d scene.

tnx.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the View3D QML type which allows you to embed 3D Content into a QQmlEngine  Window

### main.qml

```
 import QtQuick 2.14
  import QtQuick.Window 2.12
  import QtQuick3D 1.14

  Window {
      width: 1280
      height: 720
      visible: true



      View3D {
        /* put your 3d scene here */
       }

       /* overlay  item */
      Rectangle {
          width: 500
          height: 200
          anchors.margins: -10
          color: "#e0e0e0"
          border.color: "#000000"
          border.width: 1
          opacity: 0.8
      }


  }
```